# Spotify Preview API CSS Resources

Tags: css, spotify

I can't see a reference to the api.css, adam.css and eve.css files in the Preview API, nor can I find any reference to the buttons and icons they would like the app to use.

Is there a page I'm missing?

I've tried:

[Here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/preview/) and [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/integration/)
 (incompatible with Preview API)

There is also [this](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/tree/1.0) but it doesn't provide much help (other than help to decode the horrific [JSDoc site](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The monolithic api.css file have been split into separated stylesheets, each of them corresponding to a certain views module. Thus, you only need to include the CSS files for the modules you use.

Right now, these are the files:

- $views/css/list.css
- $views/css/image.css
- $views/css/buttons.css
- $views/css/throbber.css
- $views/css/popup.css

You can see them in action in the [Views tutorial preview](https://developer.spotify.com/static/builds/views-tutorial-preview.zip), and some of them are also used in the [Apps Tutorial on GitHub](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/tree/1.0).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So basically I have to open the inspector, go to resources, choose stylesheets, read through the entire css file and take a best guess at how it looks?

That's pretty crap! Also, the inspector breaks when I change between stylesheets.

Comment: You need to include a reference to those CSS files corresponding to the views modules you are using. If you are including, for instance, an `Image` view, then make sure you include `$views/css/image.css`. Every views module has its respective stylesheet. A proper CSS documentation is still missing, but that should help you as a guide.

Comment: I see, well it sucks that there's no documentation (and the JSDoc is very cumbersome/incomplete) but I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.